# How to use Key in XSLT Oxygen

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, oxygenxml

**I am trying to get the output based on two separate nodes in XML using key concept of  XSLT
I have below XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mdti:Input xmlns:mdti="urn:com.workday/multiDocumentTransform/Input">
    <mdti:Files xmlns:mdti="urn:com.workday/multiDocumentTransform/Input">
        <mdti:EventFiles>
            <mdti:File mdti:filename="first.xml" mdti:contentType="text/xml">
                <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
                    <wd:Report_Entry>
                        <wd:key>1234</wd:key>
                        <wd:comp>ABC</wd:comp>
                        <wd:asof>2021-03-24T04:59:32.179-07:00</wd:asof>
                        <wd:emplid>33333333</wd:emplid>
                        <wd:worker_type>EMP</wd:worker_type>
                        <wd:emp_type>Regular</wd:emp_type>
                        <wd:orig_hire_dt>2021-11-27</wd:orig_hire_dt>
                        <wd:rehire_dt>2019-04-01</wd:rehire_dt>
                        <wd:home_host_class>M</wd:home_host_class>
                        <wd:service_dt>2014-11-27</wd:service_dt>
                    </wd:Report_Entry>
                </wd:Report_Data>
            </mdti:File>
            <mdti:File mdti:filename="second.xml" mdti:contentType="text/xml">
                <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
                    <wd:Report_Entry>
                        <wd:key>1234</wd:key>
                        <wd:supervisor_lname>xyz</wd:supervisor_lname>
                        <wd:hr_status>A</wd:hr_status>
                        <wd:hr_status_descr>Active</wd:hr_status_descr>
                        <wd:empl_status>A</wd:empl_status>
                        <wd:empl_status_descr>Active</wd:empl_status_descr>
                        <wd:ben_status>A</wd:ben_status>
                        <wd:home_address_change_dt>2019-07-30</wd:home_address_change_dt>
                        <wd:location>444</wd:location>
                        <wd:location_descr>Ind</wd:location_descr>
                    </wd:Report_Entry>
                </wd:Report_Data>
            </mdti:File>
        </mdti:EventFiles>
    </mdti:Files>
</mdti:Input>
```

**I am using below XSLT for my data. Please let me know if I am missing something and way to do it. The only identifier in each node is the mdti:filename **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:mdti="urn:com.workday/multiDocumentTransform/Input"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    
    <xsl:key name="share" match="mdti:Input/mdti:Files/mdti:EventFiles/mdti:File/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry" use="mdti:Input/mdti:Files/mdti:EventFiles/mdti:File/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:key"/> 
    
    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <data>
            <key>1234</key>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('share', wd:key)/wd:hr_status"/>      
            <emp_type>Regular</emp_type>
            <supervisor_lname>xyz</supervisor_lname>
            <hr_status>A</hr_status>
            <location>444</location>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your question is tagged `xslt-1.0` but your stylesheet declares `version="2.0"` and requires version 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several mistakes.

First, `<xsl:template match="/">` puts you in the context of the root node; from this context, the expression  `wd:key` selects nothing - so your instruction `<xsl:copy-of select="key('share', wd:key)/wd:hr_status"/>` does nothing.

Next, if you want your key to match nodes in the second file, you should restrict it to match only nodes in the second file. Also, the `use` attribute must be relative to the matched node.

Furthermore, if you want the result to be in no-namespace, you cannot copy nodes from the input - at least not in XSLT 1.0.

There is more, but these are the ones that stand out immediately.

Consider the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:mdti="urn:com.workday/multiDocumentTransform/Input"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
exclude-result-prefixes="mdti wd">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
 
<xsl:key name="entry2" match="mdti:File[@mdti:filename='second.xml']/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry" use="wd:key"/> 
    
<xsl:template match="/mdti:Input">   
    <root> 
        <xsl:for-each select="mdti:Files/mdti:EventFiles/mdti:File[@mdti:filename='first.xml']/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry"> 
            <data>
                <!-- data from file1 -->    
                <key>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:key"/>      
                </key>
                 <emplid>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:emplid"/>      
                </emplid>
            
                <!-- data from file2 -->
                <xsl:variable name="entry2" select="key('entry2', wd:key)" />
                <supervisor_lname>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$entry2/wd:supervisor_lname"/>      
                </supervisor_lname>
                <hr_status>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$entry2/wd:hr_status"/>      
                </hr_status>
            
            </data>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </root>  
</xsl:template> 
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <data>
    <key>1234</key>
    <emplid>33333333</emplid>
    <supervisor_lname>xyz</supervisor_lname>
    <hr_status>A</hr_status>
  </data>
</root>
```

You can add fields from both branches as required.